# inserir apenas um campo com pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Eae galera, 
meu problema é o seguinte estou utilizando o objeto PDO do php para inserir registros no banco, o problema é quando eu tento inserir apenas um campo em uma tabela
exemplo:

`$query = 'INSERT INTO alunos (nome) VALUES(:nome)';
 $stmt= $conexao->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(':nome',$_POST['nome']);
 $stmt->execute();`

bem se eu tentar inserir apenas um campo não da porem se eu expecificar todos ai funciona 
exemplo:

`$query = 'INSERT INTO alunos (numero,nome,username,senha)        VALUES(:numero,:nome,:username,:senha)';
 $stmt= $conexao->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(':numero',$_POST['numero']);
 $stmt->bindValue(':nome',$_POST['nome']);
 $stmt->bindValue(':username',$_POST['username']);
 $stmt->bindValue(':senha',$_POST['senha']);
 $stmt->execute();`

será que estou fazendo algo errado no primeiro exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

falta um parenteses no final cara,
edit: vc precisa fechar a instrução do sql e ferchar o parenteses do prepare

e tente fazer assim:

```
$variavel = filter_var($_POST['nome']);
$stmt = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO alunos (nome) VALUES(:nome)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $variavel);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: sim acabei digitando errado aqui no stack porem quando eu uso eu faço certo e mesmo assim não da                                                                                      $query = "INSERT INTO alunos (nome) VALUES (:nome)";
 $stmt  = $conexao->conectar()->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
 $stmt->execute();

Comment: tentou usar o bindParam como no exemplo acima?

Comment: tente colocar $conexao->beginTransaction(); antes do $stmt->execute();

Comment: tentei usar os exemplos a cima porem, não funciona

Comment: verifique na sua tabela se por acaso os campos que você não quer inserir estão marcados como podendo ser nulos com exceção do id, do contrario não funcionara

Comment: Vlw cara realmente era isso, muito obrigado

Comment: por nada, marque a resposta como aceita.